# Sticky header table with mutiple lines in the thead

Tags: html, css

So I'm able to create a sticky header table and it works fine. The problem is that I need to make another table with a multiline header and the approach I've used so far is not working, as you can see in the code bellow.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

table tr th,
table tr td{
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 4px;
}

table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">
          Header
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">Colspan column</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          A
        </th>
        <th>
          B
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 1</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 2</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 3</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 4</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 5</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 6</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 7</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 8</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 9</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 10</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Is it possible to achive what I want using CSS only?

Here's the pen https://codepen.io/criscoder/pen/KJNGqj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, you could simply embed a table within your `<th>` and add additional rows that way.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

table tr th,
table tr td{
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 4px;
}

table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="1">
          Header
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Colspan column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">A</td>
          <td colspan="1">B</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </th>
      </tr>
      
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 1</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 2</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 3</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 4</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 5</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 6</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 7</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 8</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 9</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Line 10</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @danjones_mcr! I appreciate your help. The problem is that I'm trying to find a generic solution to this problem. Setting a fixed top position for the second line doesn't help me, because the first line of the header may not be always this tall. Do you think it's possible to find another solution without using JavaScript?

Comment: @CristianoSoares I got you, see revised answer!

Answer (score 0):

With modern browsers you can simply add position:sticky (-webkit-sticky for some IOS devices). Do note that you need to add postion:relative to the direct containers: Like the THEAD, TFoot or TBODY. Also you need to set the index order with z-index, so that the content scrolls under the sticky dom elements. So if you have sticky header and first column is also sticky (yes this works also) you need to have z-index levels for them.

If you use tables with borders on header or footer cells, this will not work correctly, the border of the header or footer scrolls with the content and disapears when scrolling the content. You may use box-shadow on the header cells to emulate border.

```css
thead,
tbody,
tfoot {
  /* cell container need relative position */
  position: relative;
}


/* sticky header */

thead th {
  /* ios devices */
  position: -webkit-sticky;

  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  /* index order is needed for the different sticky levels */
  z-index: 1;

}



/* sticky first column */
thead th:first-of-type {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

tbody td:first-of-type {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  /* sitcky TD/TH need background color */
  background-color: white;

  /* adding right borde / border gets hidden when scrol so use box-shadow: */
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0 -1px gray;

}


/* sticky footer */

tfoot th {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

tfoot th:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}





/* default styling */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --table-heading: #5D6D7E;
  --table-even: #D5D8DC;
}
body{
    font-family: Roboto, Sans-Serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto;


}

table {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table thead th,
table tfoot th {
  background-color: var(--table-heading);
  color: white;
}

table td,
table th {
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;

}

table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: var(--table-even);
}
```

```html
<p>
Resize screen width to allow horizontal scroll
</p>


<div class="container">
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                            <td>Accountant</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>63</td>
                            <td>2011/07/25</td>
                            <td>$170,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                            <td>2009/01/12</td>
                            <td>$86,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2012/03/29</td>
                            <td>$433,060</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Airi Satou</td>
                            <td>Accountant</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>33</td>
                            <td>2008/11/28</td>
                            <td>$162,700</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2012/12/02</td>
                            <td>$372,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>59</td>
                            <td>2012/08/06</td>
                            <td>$137,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>55</td>
                            <td>2010/10/14</td>
                            <td>$327,900</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>39</td>
                            <td>2009/09/15</td>
                            <td>$205,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>2008/12/13</td>
                            <td>$103,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2008/12/19</td>
                            <td>$90,560</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                            <td>Support Lead</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2013/03/03</td>
                            <td>$342,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>36</td>
                            <td>2008/10/16</td>
                            <td>$470,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>43</td>
                            <td>2012/12/18</td>
                            <td>$313,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>19</td>
                            <td>2010/03/17</td>
                            <td>$385,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michael Silva</td>
                            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                            <td>2012/11/27</td>
                            <td>$198,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2010/06/09</td>
                            <td>$725,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gloria Little</td>
                            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>59</td>
                            <td>2009/04/10</td>
                            <td>$237,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                            <td>2012/10/13</td>
                            <td>$132,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Dai Rios</td>
                            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>35</td>
                            <td>2012/09/26</td>
                            <td>$217,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                            <td>Development Lead</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2011/09/03</td>
                            <td>$345,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                            <td>2009/06/25</td>
                            <td>$675,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>2011/12/12</td>
                            <td>$106,450</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>Sydney</td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>2010/09/20</td>
                            <td>$85,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/10/09</td>
                            <td>$1,200,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>42</td>
                            <td>2010/12/22</td>
                            <td>$92,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>2010/11/14</td>
                            <td>$357,650</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>2011/06/07</td>
                            <td>$206,850</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fiona Green</td>
                            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>48</td>
                            <td>2010/03/11</td>
                            <td>$850,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shou Itou</td>
                            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>2011/08/14</td>
                            <td>$163,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michelle House</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>Sydney</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2011/06/02</td>
                            <td>$95,400</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Suki Burks</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>53</td>
                            <td>2009/10/22</td>
                            <td>$114,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                            <td>Technical Author</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>2011/05/07</td>
                            <td>$145,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                            <td>Team Leader</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2008/10/26</td>
                            <td>$235,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>46</td>
                            <td>2011/03/09</td>
                            <td>$324,050</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Unity Butler</td>
                            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/12/09</td>
                            <td>$85,675</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>51</td>
                            <td>2008/12/16</td>
                            <td>$164,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                            <td>Secretary</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                            <td>2010/02/12</td>
                            <td>$109,850</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                            <td>Financial Controller</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>62</td>
                            <td>2009/02/14</td>
                            <td>$452,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2008/12/11</td>
                            <td>$136,200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                            <td>Director</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>65</td>
                            <td>2008/09/26</td>
                            <td>$645,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2011/02/03</td>
                            <td>$234,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>38</td>
                            <td>2011/05/03</td>
                            <td>$163,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2009/08/19</td>
                            <td>$139,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Thor Walton</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2013/08/11</td>
                            <td>$98,540</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/07/07</td>
                            <td>$87,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2012/04/09</td>
                            <td>$138,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>63</td>
                            <td>2010/01/04</td>
                            <td>$125,250</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>56</td>
                            <td>2012/06/01</td>
                            <td>$115,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>43</td>
                            <td>2013/02/01</td>
                            <td>$75,650</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>46</td>
                            <td>2011/12/06</td>
                            <td>$145,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2011/03/21</td>
                            <td>$356,250</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Lael Greer</td>
                            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>2009/02/27</td>
                            <td>$103,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2010/07/14</td>
                            <td>$86,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shad Decker</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>51</td>
                            <td>2008/11/13</td>
                            <td>$183,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>29</td>
                            <td>2011/06/27</td>
                            <td>$183,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Donna Snider</td>
                            <td>Customer Support</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>2011/01/25</td>
                            <td>$112,000</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This answers the question of how to have a a sticky/frozen header, footer, and column.  This is different from the question of how to have multiple sticky/frozen rows in a table header.